# What is the current status of official 5e Naval Combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, vehicles

In May of 2019, *[Ghosts of Saltmarsh](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/source/ghosts-of-saltmarsh)* was released bringing official rules for naval combat in the form of *Appendix A: Of Ships and the Sea*. This appears to be the culmination of the [published](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA_ShipsSea.pdf) "Unearthed Arcana" versions of the same name.

However, there is still the [Ships and Sailing](https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/ships-and-sailing/) material from the [5th Edition SRD](https://www.5esrd.com/), and there are significant differences between that and the *GoSM Appendix A*. I understand that this material is the Open Source information Wizards of the Coast allows people to use in their own published material. I'm just confused as to while WotC would have Open Source info that contradicted their official published material.

Question: Does WotC have two different official material for rules for naval combat? Which is the definitive set of rules?

Comment: Are you sure those are officially pubished rules and not some homebrewed adaptation? I do not see anything on this site which might tell about it official status or WotC affiliation.

Comment: Those rules do not appear in the D&D 5e SRD, which can be found [here on the Wizards of the Coast website](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd). As far as I know, they do not appear in any official D&D 5e book.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot That site does mark some of its content as 3rd party (3pp), but does not appear to have one on the linked content.

Comment: If you look at the "breadcrumbs" at the top of the linked page, you can see that this is part of a section called "gamemastering". There are definitely other sections in there which are not marked 3pp but which are also not from the SRD. Honestly, I'd just avoid this site entirely.

Comment: It took some sleuthing, but the rules presented at https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/ships-and-sailing/ appear to be lifted from [Ultimate Ships 5E](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/239871/Ultimate-Ships-5E), by third-party publisher Legendary Games.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## There *are* two sets of rules for ship combat, but the ones you link are not both official

The first set of rules we get for ship combat appears in the [Unusual Environments section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/adventure-environments#TheSea) of Chapter 5 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*:

> Traveling through the wilderness doesn’t always mean an overland trek. Adventurers might ply the open sea in a caravel or an elemental-powered galleon...

The rules here are very sparse and not the most detailed, but include such things as describing the HP and defenses of various ships.

---

The later addition of the rules from *Ghosts of Saltmarsh* provide a much needed improvement on these rules for that setting. These rules appear in Appendix A of the book under [Ships in Combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/gos/of-ships-and-the-sea#ShipsinCombat):

> Whether sailing to war or hunting notorious pirates, ships make deadly weapons and dramatic battlefields. This section provides guidance on using ships in combat.

### The D&D 5e SRD

The D&D 5e SRD does not contain *any* rules about ship combat. I'm not sure what the source of the rules you link are, but I don't recognize them from any official rulebook. You can find the actual D&D 5e SRD [on the Wizards of the Coast website](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd).